# redgate ants profiler instrumentation like Enterprise library 5 Logging TraceManager

Tags: logging, instrumentation, enterprise-library-5, red-gate-ants

Is it possible to use Ants profiler instrumentation component api like enterprise library logging/instrumentation?
I want to instrument certain part of my application on end user's machine.
I also want it to be configurable, so that it wont kick-off all time.

In short, instead of using antsprofiler, I want to use ants-profiler libraries in my application. As it won't be possible to deploy and use ants profiler on end user's machine.
I can then collect dump from enduser machine and interpret to know loop-holes.

Share your experience if you have done anything similar to this.

Redgate site reference - http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/knowledgebase/ANTS_Performance_Profiler/KB200708000092

Answer (score 0):

ANTS Performance Profiler does not feature a supported API for local deployments or as part of another assembly, so I am afraid you will be unable to use its libraries in the way that you describe above.

Out of curiosity what is the type of application you want to profile in such a way? Desktop, web, service ?